# How to fix "there is no unique or primary key constraint on table" sql error in javafx?

Tags: sql, derby

I don't know what is the problem because the MEMBER table has a primary key..

```
void setupBookTable() {
        String TABLE_NAME = "BOOK";
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null,null, TABLE_NAME.toUpperCase(),null);
            if (tables.next()) {
                System.out.println("A " + TABLE_NAME + " már készen áll!");
            } else {
                stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                        + "  id varchar(200) primary key,\n"
                        + "  title varchar(200),\n"
                        + "  author varchar(200),\n"
                        + "  publisher varchar(200),\n"
                        + "  isAvail boolean default true"
                        + " )");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " .. setupDatabase");
        } finally {
        }
    }

    void setupMemberTable() {
        String TABLE_NAME = "MEMBER";
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null,null, TABLE_NAME.toUpperCase(),null);
            if (tables.next()) {
                System.out.println("A " + TABLE_NAME + " asztal már készen áll!");
            } else {
                stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                        + "name varchar(50), "
                        + "ID varchar(100) primary key, "
                        + "mobile varchar(25), "
                        + "email varchar(100))");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " .. setupDatabase");
        } finally {
        }
    }

    void setupKiadTable() {
        String TABLE_NAME = "KIAD";
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, TABLE_NAME.toUpperCase(), null);
            if (tables.next()){
                System.out.println("A " + TABLE_NAME + " asztal már készen áll!");
            } else {
                stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                        + "  bookID varchar(200) primary key,\n"
                        + "  memberID varchar(200),\n"
                        + "  kiadTime timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n"
                        + "  megujit_count integer default 0,\n"
                        + "  FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES BOOK(id),\n"
                        + "  FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES MEMBER(ID))\n");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " --- adatbázis felállítás");
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

I got this error:

> "Constraint 'SQL190509155106120' is invalid: there is no unique or
>   primary key constraint on table '"APP"."MEMBER"' that matches the
>   number and types of the columns in the foreign key. --- adatbázis
>   felállítás"

Comment: removed the fx tag because I don't see any relation - if there is any, please explain, best by providing a [mcve] that demonstrates how the problem appears when accessing the db from a fx context vs. without such a context.

Comment: Did you try running those CREATE TABLE statements interactively, using a tool like Derby's `ij` tool, on an empty database? If so, and you get an error that way, try posting that exact transcript of that SQL session with `ij`

Comment: i got the same error.

Comment: i found the problem. The "member" table's id has varchar(100), but the "kiad" table's memberID has varchar(200).